What is the relationship between SLA and RTO
An Azure based vendor solution published Service Level Availability (SLA) as 99.9% (calculated monthly) with a Recovery Time Objective (RTO) of 8 hours.
With a month equal to 720 hours, an uptime of 99.9%, the system will need to be available 719.28 hours.
Is the RTO of 8 hours logically possible with an SLA of 99.9%?

Usually SLA is defined for year, not month. And for 8760 hours, 99.9% are 8h 41m 38s. (you can calculate here)
So if you have one recover per year and RTO is 8 hours you perfectly fit in SLA.

These are two different but related measurements.
With a 99.9% uptime SLA you are eligible for compensation if the service is unavailable for longer than the contracted amount of time.
The RTO applies in a recovery scenario. If recovery to the contracted point requires more time than RTO, you may be eligible for compensation.
Being in a recovery scenario implies that the uptime SLA has been breached. A recovery  longer than eight hours would be another, separate breach.

Being in a recovery scenario implies that the uptime SLA has been breached. — How? I was about to answer the same as @RomeoNinov, he was just a bit faster; he shows the calculation that shows how you can have a recovery with that much of RTO as a means to fulfill an SLA without breaching it.

If the recovery scenario is the fault of the provider, the uptime SLA is implicitly breached.
